# ${\rm Hom}_R(M, R/M) =\{0\} \implies R$ is a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a local ring with maximal ideal $M$. Suppose $M$ is finitely generated. Prove that if ${\rm Hom}_R(M, R/M) =\{0\}$, then $R$ is a field.

${\rm Hom}_R(M, R/M)$ stand for the group of $R$-module homomorphisms from $M$ to the quotient $R/M$.

Comment: You initially put $hom(R,R/M)$ and $hom(M,R/M)$, and then soneone edited them to be the same. Which did you want?

Comment: @rschwieb: It must be $\text{Hom}(M, R/M)$, as $\text{Hom}(R,R/M) \cong R/M$ is in fact never $0$

Comment: It should be $hom(M,R/M)$

Comment: What does Hom mean in this case?  $R$-module Hom?

Comment: @Seth: Ring homomorphisms.

Comment: $M$ doesn't have a unit though.  I mean it's still a ring under certain definitions of ring but that seems strange to me.

Comment: @algor207: I believe you mean $R$-module homomorphisms ($M$ is not a ring)

Comment: @algor207: I've made some more edits, to what I believe is the correct statement. Please feel free to edit further if this is not what you meant

Comment: Thanks again for the edits. Yes, it should be $R$-module homomorphisms.

Comment: Dear @zcn : this is my way of drawing attention to mistakes like this. I always ask before making an edit that decides the entire nature of a question, to make sure. It doesn't mean I can't see what's obvious and am actually asking a question. Give a little credit, eh?

Comment: Pardon my mistakes. I just edited the question to "Suppose $R/M$ is finitely generated" instead of "Suppose $M$ is finitely generated".

Comment: @rschwieb: I'm a little confused by your comment. To clarify, my comment was not entirely directed at you (though it may seem as if it was) - it was to ensure, with certainty, to later viewers what the correct statement should be. Of course I'm sure that you already knew what the correct statement was

Comment: @algor207: $R/M$ is always finitely generated as an $R$-module (by the class of $1$). As both answers have shown, one really needs $M$   finitely generated to proceed

Comment: Dear @zcn : I will try to imagine a more conspiratorial tone, then, if you answer one of my rhetorical questions @ me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course i find zcn's answer very instructive, however i think there is a more low-tech proof:

Suppose $R$ is not a field. Then $M \neq 0$ or equivalently by Nakayama $M \neq M^2$ (since $M$ is finitely generated).
Hence there exists an element $x \in M$ whose class $\bar{x}$ in $M/M^2$ is non-zero. Since $M/M^2$ is an $R/M$ vector space, we can define a nonzero $R/M$ homomorphism $f:M/M^2 \rightarrow R/M$ which is the projection onto the subspace spanned by $\bar{x}$. Now compose $f$ with the natural projection $\pi: M \rightarrow M/M^2$ to get a non-zero $R$-homomorphism $f \circ \pi : M \rightarrow R/M$.

This shows that if $R$ is not a field we must have $\operatorname{Hom}_R(M,R/M) \neq 0$.

Answer (score 6):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{\operatorname{Hom}}$By [tensor-Hom adjointness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor-hom_adjunction), $$\Hom_R(M, R/M) \cong \Hom_R(M, \Hom_{R/M}(R/M, R/M)) \cong \Hom_{R/M}(M \otimes_R R/M, R/M) \cong \Hom_{R/M}(M/M^2, R/M) = (M/M^2)^*$$ where $*$ denotes vector space dual over the field $R/M$. Thus $(M/M^2)^* = 0 \iff M/M^2 = 0 \iff M = 0$ by Nakayama's Lemma (since $M$ is finitely generated), i.e. $R$ is a field.

Comment: Is there any way you can think of solving this without the tensor-hom adjointness?

Comment: @algor207: Is there any particular reason you wish to solve this without tensor-hom adjointness? It is a rather fundamental fact...

Comment: @Seth: The reason being that I'm not familiar with them and the place I pulled the question from, first defined a module, then defined what it means to be finitely generated. Thus my assumption (probably wrong assumption) is that it can be done without that.

Comment: @algor207: I see. I don't currently have a more low-tech approach, but one could try tracing through the isomorphisms, to see explicitly why a (nonzero) generator of $M$ gives rise to a (nonzero) homomorphism $M \to R/M$ (by the way, my username is zcn)

Comment: @zen What I think it is, is that ${\rm Hom}_R(M, R/M) \cong {\rm Hom}_R(M, R)$. This is building on what you previously suggested i.e ${\rm Hom}_R(M, M) \cong {\rm Hom}_R(M, R)$ and ${\rm Hom}_R(M, R)$ surgects onto ${\rm Hom}_R(M, R/M)$. (by the way, don't why I confused zen for seth)

Comment: @Manos: However, $R/M$ is flat over $R$ iff $M = 0$, which happens to be exactly what we're trying to show. Also, congratulations for following through with my hint for a low-tech approach: +1